# CSS custom shape

Tags: css, shapes, css-shapes

How can I make something like this:

[image]

By now I have: jsfiddle.net/xmqfe3h0/9

```
#test {
width: 315px;
height: 90%;
position: relative;
}

#test:before {
content: "";
position: absolute;
left: 70%;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-left: 10px solid transparent;
border-right: 10px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 50px solid black;   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add skew to your css3 shape :

```
  -webkit-transform: skew(40deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(40deg);
  -o-transform: skew(40deg);
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xmqfe3h0/10/)

Answer (score 0):

You must split it into rectangles and triangles. Triangles can be produced with CSS transformations (nested boxes with rotation). You must set the correct positions of the background image.